# Using Selenium and conditional xpath to click element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, conditional-statements

Currently I am learning to use selenium to automate testing. One of my task is to click to the next page on a website. The xpath I copied from the specific button is the following:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="pagination"]/div/div[1]/a[4]'
```

So when I use driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click() it will bring me to the next page.

To click through multiple pages I would like to find the specified element based on the condition that the text is equal to the correct page.

For this I tried the following conditional xpath:

> xpath = //*[@id="pagination"]/div/div[1]/a[text()='page_num']

where page_num is the specific page I want to click on.

Example:
for the follwing element I would use the xpath:

```
element = <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0s.ds-center.0.0">2</a> 

xpath = //*[@id="pagination"]/div/div[1]/a[text()='2']
```

I would expect that selenium would click to the specified page but instead I get an Error message that the xpath doesn't exist.

What should be the correct conditional xpath name?

Comment: Can you post the link to the page you are trying to scrape?

Comment: link is the following: https://home.aliexpress.com/dropshipper/ds_center.htm

Comment: The xpath you are using seems to be fine. May be the way you are concatenating page_num may be incorrect. Could you please paste your code, then can have a look.